# Common request response interceptor for WCF and MVC Web API in C#

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

**Some Background:**
We have lot of Web APIs and Services projects, Some of them are in WCF and some of them are in MVC Web API framework. My intension is to develop a common request/response interceptor library for all of them which can log request and response my doing minimalistic change in actual project.
I know that we can use ActionFilters for MVC Web APIs and MessageInspector in WCF to achieve this task.

**My Question:**
Is it possible to create a common request/response interceptor library for MVC WebAPIs and WCF services? If not I think I have to create two different libraries to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the IClientMessageInspector interface on the client side, and implement the IDispatchMessageInspector interface on the server side. You can intercept requests and replies.

This is sample code on the client:

```
  public class ClientMessageLogger : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        string outputstr = $"Server reply message received by the client:\n{reply}\n";
        Console.WriteLine(outputstr);
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        string outputText = $"The request message that the client will send:\n{request}\n";
        Console.WriteLine(outputText);
        return null;

    }
}
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface)]
public class CustomBehavior : Attribute, IContractBehavior
{
    public Type TargetContract => typeof(ServiceReference1.ICalculator);
    public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        return;
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(new ClientMessageLogger());
    }
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
    {
        return;
    }

    public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

This is sample code on the server:

```
 public class CustomMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
    {
        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            string displayText = $"The request message received by the server:\n{request}\n";
            Console.WriteLine(displayText);
            return null;
        }

        public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            string displayText = $"Server reply message:\n{reply}\n";
            Console.WriteLine(displayText);
        }
    }
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface)]
    public class CustomBehavior : Attribute, IContractBehavior
    {
        public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
            return;
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
            return;
        }
        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
        {
            dispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new CustomMessageInspector());
        }

        public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Finally, you need to apply `[CustomBehavior]` above the interface.

[image]

Comment: I believe this is only possible in case of WCF and not MVC Web API projects, Is my understanding is not correct?

Comment: It can be used in MVC.

Comment: I tested, It will not work with MVC, For MVC we either have to use DelegateHandler or ActionFilter. If you think it can be used with MVC Web API where we use controllers, Please present an example in your answer